# Creating concrete XML files with XML Data Binding Wizard in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi

I want to create concrete data using Edit fields for input in Delphi 10.4 and XML Data Binding Wizard.

I have the XML schema and I used it to create the code below in Delphi.

Can you help me with the code below how to create concrete XML files?

This is what I got from the Data Binding Wizard:

```
function NewUnknown: IXMLGetBalance_Type;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('Unknown', TXMLGetBalance_Type, TargetNamespace) as IXMLGetBalance_Type;
end;

{ TXMLGetBalance_Type }

procedure TXMLGetBalance_Type.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('consent', TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent);
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLGetBalance_Type.Get_Consent: IXMLGetBalance_Type_consent;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['consent'] as IXMLGetBalance_Type_consent;
end;

{ TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent }

function TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent.Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['type'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent.Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  ChildNodes['type'].NodeValue := Value;
end;

function TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent.Get_Target: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['target'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent.Set_Target(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  ChildNodes['target'].NodeValue := Value;
end;

function TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent.Get_Id: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['id'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLGetBalance_Type_consent.Set_Id(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  ChildNodes['id'].NodeValue := Value;
end;
```

How can I use this code to create concrete XML files with data from Edit fields?

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understood now that. 
I have 1 more question, i am trying to connect to an API like this wich is not working : request :=(HTTPRio1 as AccountInfo_PT).getBalance(Unk); because the getBalance() function has parameter type getBalance wichs definition is in the WSDL file wich i imported so getBalance() function wants getBalance class type parameter wich is of class getBalance_type , how can i create this getBalance parameter from Unk wich is IXMLGetBalance_Type  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `NewUnknown()`, assign values to the properties of the returned `IXMLGetBalance_Type` as needed, and then save it to file. For example:

```pascal
uses
  ..., UnitGeneratedByXMLWizard;

procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  Unk: IXMLGetBalance_Type;
begin
  Unk := NewUnknown;
  Unk.Consent.Type_ := ...;
  Unk.Consent.Target := ...;
  Unk.Consent.Id := ...;
  Unk.SaveToFile('path_to\myfile.xml');
end;
```

Have a look at Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Using Code That the XML Data Binding Wizard Generates](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Code_That_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard_Generates)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understood now.

Comment: I have 1 more question, i am trying to connect to an API like this wich is not working : request :=(HTTPRio1 as AccountInfo_PT).getBalance(Unk); because the getBalance() function has parameter type getBalance wichs definition is in the WSDL file wich i imported so getBalance() function wants getBalance class type parameter wich is of class getBalance_type , how can i create this getBalance parameter from Unk wich is IXMLGetBalance_Type